# overflow hidden not working on touch device

Tags: touch, overflow, hidden

I have a problem with overflow:hidden on a touch device.
Basically I have my html and body on overflow:hidden. With a contact form outside(bottom) of the window. On clicking a button this form will animate in. This is so far working great on desktop browsers.

But on touch devices, I seem to be able to scroll down and view the form. I can't seem to find solutions after much googling. Is there anyway to force overflow:hidden on touch devices?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use display:none

display: none removes the element from the page, and the flow of the page acts as if it's not there at all.
The overflow property specifies what to do if the content of an element exceeds the size of the element's box.